# R data manupulation and Chi-square test

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a data frame:

```
gender   group   count    total
female    A       8        10
female    B       23       30
female    C       22       25
male      A       18       28
male      B       23       30
male      C       40       70
```

How should I process data and apply the chi-square test for each group between genders?

Answer (score 2):

First its handy to use dput function to make it easy for your data to be reproduced

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(gender = c("female", "female", "female", "male",
"male", "male"), group = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), count = c(8L,
23L, 22L, 18L, 23L, 40L), total = c(10L, 30L, 25L, 28L, 30L,
70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)).
```

then you can use the by function by group (or gender) like this

```
by(dat, dat$group, function(x) chisq.test(data.frame(x$count, x$total)))
dat$group: A

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  data.frame(x$count, x$total)
X-squared = 0.011266, df = 1, p-value = 0.9155
```

---

```
dat$group: B

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  data.frame(x$count, x$total)
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

---

```
dat$group: C

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  data.frame(x$count, x$total)
X-squared = 1.0981, df = 1, p-value = 0.2947
```

Its worth making sure its testing exactly what you want though by looking at the 2*2 matrix this method creates:

eg

```
> by(dat, dat$group, function(x)data.frame(x$count, x$total))[1]
$A
  x.count x.total
1       8      10
2      18      28
```